# Upload image to parse using AngularJS upload form

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, upload

Simple question, how to create an angularjs upload form to Parse.com?
I am trying to create a profile picture uploader form using using this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889064/uploading-files-to-parse-com-with-javascript), but it not works

HTML code

```
<div class="col-lg-9"  ng-controller="manageProfile">
    <form style="margin-top:80px">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Browse for Picture</label>
            <input type="file" name="profPic" id="profPic"></input>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-md" ng-click="uploadPicture()">Upload Picture</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

AngularJS code

```
profile.controller('manageProfile', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.uploadPicture = function() {
    var fileUploadControl = $("#profPic")[0];
    var file = fileUploadControl.file[0];
    var name = file.name;
    var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);

    parseFile.save().then(function() {
        var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
        currentUser.set("profilePicture", parseFile);
        currentUser.save();
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + ' ' + error.message);
    });
}
```

I got this error when trying to upload

```
error: fileuploadcontrol is undefined
```

Comment: Show the code that you have tried.

Comment: Also look at [parse-angular-patch](https://github.com/trycom/parse-angular-patch)

Comment: i am sorry for not writing the code right away...

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS, input elements use the `ng-model` directive to bind input to a scope variable.

```
<div class="col-lg-9"  ng-controller="manageProfile">
    <form style="margin-top:80px">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Browse for Picture</label>
               <!-- add ng-model directive -->
            <input ng-model="fileName" type="file" name="profPic" id="profPic"></input>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-md" ng-click="uploadPicture()">Upload Picture</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
profile.controller('manageProfile', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.uploadPicture = function() {
        /* replace this
        var fileUploadControl = $("#profPic")[0];
        var file = fileUploadControl.file[0];
        var name = file.name;
        */
        //Use ng-model variable
        var name = $scope.fileName;
        //
    };

}]);
```

For more information on `ng-model`, see [AngularJS ng-model Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).

Comment: done change the code just like the answer, but still got `Error: this._source is undefined`